# RxJava (Android) - Intermediate step on error, retry after error resolution

Tags: rx-java, chaining

I am currently trying to get myself into RxJava.

---

Now I have the following scenario:
I have to authenticate a user.

The steps that I need to do for this are the following:

1. Try to authenticate user using locally stored token
2. If authentication fails (due to token expiration) try to get a new token using a locally stored
   refresh token
3. Alternatives:

   - On success:

     1. Save the newly fetched token locally
     2. Try to authenticate again, if this fails, show error
   - On failure (because also the refresh token expired): Show login dialog
   - On failure (because of other reasons): Show error

---

What I have already implemented are 2 Observables, one for the authentication, one for the refresh of the token.
Those return 2 different types of results.

---

I now struggle to chain those into the steps mentioned above.
Is there someone that could give me a hint?

Or is this more a case for a separate class to handle this procedure instead of a RxJava chain (because too complex)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done in a simpler way using an error handling operator `onErrorResumeNext()` which pass control to another Observable rather than invoking `onError()`, if the observable encounters an error.

Let's assume your 2 observables are:

```
// Assuming authenticate returns an exception of typeA if it fails
Observable<A> authenticate;
// returns an exception of typeB if refresh fails
Observable<B> refresh;
```

Now let's create another observable using concatMap.

```
// Probably you want to emit token from refresh observable. If not,
// then I hope you will get the idea how it's done. 
Observable<Object> refreshThenAuthenticate = refresh.concatMap(new Func1<A, Observable<B>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<A> call(B b) {
            // create an authentication observable using the token
            return createAuthenticateObservable(b.getToken());
        }
});
// Above can be written in much simpler form if you use Java 8 lambdas.


/* first authenticate will be executed, if it fails then control will
 * go to refreshThenAuthenticate.
 */
authenticate
.onErrorResumeNext(refreshThenAuthenticate)
.subscribe(new Observer<A>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
               // login successful
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                // if e of typeA show login dialog
                // else do something else
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(A a) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this directs me into the correct direction. Unfortunately I have the problem that the observable of authenticate has an other type than the one for refresh ( `Observable<A>, Observable<B>`). Now I cant use the concatted observable inside `onErrorResumeNext`. Is there a solution for this without the need of changing the signatures of the two observables?

Comment: Thank you, `concatMap` brought me onto the right track!